# plsql stored procedure with Input parameter date_of_birth as varchar in 'DD-MM-YYYY' format

Tags: sql, plsql

```
create or replace procedure pr1(i in varchar,o out sys_refcursor)
as begin
open o for
select sid,sname
from students
where dob=i;
end;
/


variable x refcursor
```

exec pr1(i=>d.o.b,o=>:x) actually i dont know how to given a date input in paratmeter???? display the details in students table???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual DOB parameter would be a string formatted according to the given format model. This model (ie.its string representation) is used in the query to convert properly between the input string and the db column of type date (the latter is guesswork of course).

Your code - and hence the snippet below - are incomplete, but you know that.

```
create or replace procedure pr1(i in varchar,o out sys_refcursor)
as begin
    open o for
        select sid,sname
          from students
         where dob=TO_DATE(i, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
    ;
   end;
/

variable x refcursor
exec pr1(i => '24-12-1999', o => :x)
```